# How to obtain an installer for True DB List 6.0

Tags: vb6

I maintain a legacy application, built with VB6. It uses the third party control True DB List 6.0. The installaer for that component that I have access to does not work, and appears to have been corrupted. Can anyone suggest a method of obtaining a non-corrupt installer for this now-ancient component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that ancient. It's still on sale, so you could [buy the latest version](http://www.componentsource.com/products/componentone-studio-activex/index-gbp.html) again?

Or contact componentsource, explain what's happened, and hope that they will let you have the installer free. This will probably work better if you have a record of the original purchase. Of course, you'd probably have an uncorrupted copy of the installer too if you still had a record of the original purchase.

Comment: I don't want to have to purchase something I already have! Plus, the later version is not what we have installed on our (working) Citrix servers...thanks anyway for the suggestion, might have to check in with component source.